# input variable inside of a function output outside of function

Tags: python, object, variables, global, new-operator

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm making an adventure "game" to help me learn. The player has a bit of dialogue to get through and a decision to make, which leads to different choices, two of which ask for their name. I can't seem to make the player_name variable appear in the next function, it just stays blank. I just want it as a global variable where I can continue to use it throughout the game.

```html
   
player_name = ("")

def path_2():
    print("I found you lying in the hallway.")
    print("Maybe I should have left you there...")
    player_name = input("What is your name? : ")
    return player_name

def path_1():
    print("It's a pleasure to meet you.")
    print ("My name is Azazel. I am the warden of this place.")
    print ("I found you lying in the hallway,")
    print ("bleeding profusely from you head there.")
    print ("")
    player_name = input("What is your name? : ")
    return player_name

def quest():
    print(("This is a long story ")+str(player_name)+(" you'll have to be patient."))
    enter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing player_name = input("What is your name? : "), you're re-defining player_name  in the scope of your function, so it's no longer pointing to the global variable, what you could do is:

```
def path_2():
  print("I found you lying in the hallway.")
  print("Maybe I should have left you there...")
  global player_name 
  player_name = input("What is your name? : ")
```

Notice that you don't need to return player name, because you're modifying the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

use global keyword before using the same variable in a function

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of concepts here that you'll need to sharpen up on to make this work.  The first is the *scope* of a variable.  The second is parameters and return values of functions.  Briefly (you should research this more), the variables you create in a function are not visible outside that function.  If you `return` a value, then you can catch it from the calling location.  Using global variables is possible, but usually not the best approach.  Consider:

```
def introduce():
  player_name = input("tell me your name: ")
  print("welcome, {}".format(player_name))
  return player_name
def creepy_dialogue(p_name, item):
  print("What are you doing with that {}, {}?".format(item, p_name))

# start the story and get name
name = introduce()

weapon = "knife"
creepy_dialogue(name, weapon)
```